# jquery .each produces 'undefined' whenever .data is used on the elements returned

Tags: dom, iteration, jquery

I'm trying to process all select elements with a specific `data-` attribute set.

I've got the loop working to pick up the element, but whenever I try to find the value of its other `data-` attributes I get `undefined` error messages.

Here is the loop:

```
$('select[data-hm-observed="1"]').each(function(idx, sel) {
        alert(sel.getAttribute('data-hm-url'));
        alert(sel.data('hmUrl'));
});
```

In the loop the first alert works, but the second produces:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating
>   'sel.data('hmUrl')')

If I use the Safari console I can get the select object, put it in a variable, and interrogate its `data-` attributes without issue.

It seems that the `.each()` is having an effect on the `sel` variable contents - but I can't understand what.

Using JQuery 1.7.1

**UPDATE:**

Just discovered that if I change the loop so that it explicitly gets the element again, it all works:

```
$('select[data-hm-observed="1"]').each(function(idx, sel) {
            xx = $(sel);
        alert(sel.getAttribute('data-hm-url'));
        alert(xx.data('hmUrl'));
});
```

Is this the correct solution?
Can I infer from this that the element passed into the loop by .each hasn't been 'processed' by jquery, and that I have to pull it myself via $(...) so that jquery does its stuff to it - this doesn't feel right - but its working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sel` is a DOM Object here, not equipped with the abilities of a jQuery Object. First, you should turn this DOM Object into a jQuery Object like this:

```
alert( $(sel).data('hmUrl') );
```

Alternatively, you can also use `$(this).data('hmUrl')`, because `this` will refer to `sel` (the current DOM element in the iteration).

- See also [`.each()` 2nd Example](http://api.jquery.com/each/#example-1)

Comment: Excellent thank you. Is there a reason why .each returns it as a dom and not a jquery object?

Comment: @Houdi Under the hood, the jQuery "collection" is an array of DOM elements. When iterating, you get these DOM elements. Basically, when you do `$(sel)`, you create a new jQuery collection holding only this one object. And in several cases, you do not need jQuery methods, simple DOM stuff suffice (`console.log(this.id)` in the `.each()` will work fine).